# why does index.html keep opening as https://www.google.com/index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to check for a keyword in the url and launch an html file from javascript

here is my code:

```
window.setInterval(function doTheTing() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("keyword") > -1) {
            window.location.replace("index.html")
        }
    }, 1000)
```

what im trying to do is open the file when the keyword is in url, and it does work, but for some reason when i try to open index.html it opens https://www.google.com/index.html instead

*if the keyword is in the url of a youtube video than it opens as https://www.youtube.com/index.html (which isnt a real domain so it just shows an error page)

*if its from a tiktok than https://www.tiktok.com/index.html (which also returns an error page)

and so on...

how can i just open index.html?

thanks for the help

Comment: You need to understand: *what is index.html?* - it's a file the browser requested at a server. If you do not specify the server, it will default to the one site (server) you are currently on.  If you want to open a *specific* file, you need to tell the browser which server to find it at.

Comment: Try with `window.location.replace(chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"))`. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL).

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko    it just takes me to: chrome-extension://invalid/

Comment: Where is the `index.html` file located?